# Can I change quick launch buttons apps for Compaq Cq62-259TU running Win7

Tags: windows-7, compaq-laptop

I just got Compaq CQ62-259TU, I downloaded the "HP quick launch button software", but when I install it the installation wizard runs, but after the progress bar reaches 100%, it disappears, and no other window pop ups.
Quick launch buttons are working, but I can't see the software of HP Quick Launch buttons nor the Fn + ESC, is opening any program.
Also like to ask, can I change the apps of quick launch buttons.

Comment: Hello Darrin,

I have done this and successfully disabled the calculator key.  However, when trying to disable the print key by clearing the execute string, the print key remains active.  Would this change perhaps require a reboot?

I really only care about those two since they are the ones I am continually hitting for the control key (bad typist that i am...).

Thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to the start bar in Windows 7, type “regedit” and press enter. If you’re unfamiliar with the Windows registry then please be careful, messing with values here can cause a lot of errors.

Navigate to the registry folder:

Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\AppKey

In the folder you’ll see more folders, the three we care about are:

- 15 calls for the Assocation of mailto
- 16 calls for the Assocation of .cda
- 7 calls for the Assocation of http (opens the browser or program associated with http)
- 17 calls for a ShellExecute of ::{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}
- 18 calls for the Assocation of calc.exe

These are the mail, CD, Internet, Print, Calculator buttons respectively.

If you want to change them, simply modify  the values inside each folder. Association will open the program that is tied to the protocol or file type.  ShellExecute on the other hand is the same as typing something into Run and pressing enter.

An example: Let’s say you want the mail button to open Notepad: Go into the folder named 15, rename “Association” to “ShellExecute”, double click ShellExecute to modify the key’s data and enter “notepad.exe”, replacing “mailto.”

Want to disable a button? Just clear out the ShellExecute or Association data. For the mail button you would double click the Association and replace “mailto” with nothing.

Comment: how would I assign the mailto button to be another `start` button?